# Use of forName and Class.forName and isInstance

Tags: java, reflection

I want to pass a name of a class as an argument in a print method.
For example : `public void printAll(String className)`
I've also created a list of animals.
I want to print only the nodes that belong in class with name className.

i tried to use something like this :

```
node tmp;
if (Class.forName(className).isInstance(tmp.getValue())
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
if (tmp.getValue.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName(className).newInstance())) { 
      //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the class names as stings:

```
if (className.equals(tmp.getValue().getClass().getName()) {
    // do something
}
```